# Shell Script - Read lines of a file and uses it to get data from another file which uses it to echo a command

Tags: bash, shell

Good day. I'm pretty new at shell scripting and I've searched online for an answer but I can't figure out how to do it myself. Apologies if this has been asked before, been searching for hours but could not find any.

I have the shell script below.

```
file1="pet_list.txt"
while read -r file1; do
STRING=$(paste $file1.breed.txt)
echo "My pet is a $file1 and the breed is $STRING"
done < "$file1"
```

What result I wanted is

```
My pet is a dog and the breed is chowchow
My pet is a dog and the breed is pitbull
My pet is a dog and the breed is bulldog
My pet is a cat and the breed is sphynx
My pet is a cat and the breed is Bengal
```

But im currently getting the result below.

```
My pet is a dog and the breed is chowchow
pitbull
bulldog
My pet is a cat and the breed is sphynx
Bengal
```

I have 3 files which are the below. Is there a way to get the result that I wanted? Any help is appreciated.

```
$ ls
pet_list.txt
dog.breed.txt
cat.breed.txt
$ cat dog.breed.txt
chowchow
pitbull
bulldog
$ cat cat.breed.txt
sphynx
Bengal
$ cat pet_list.txt
dog
cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit of the issue you raise seems to be the line
`STRING=$(paste $file1.breed.txt)`

because the file `*.breed.txt` you are interested in is taken in one go, instead of looking at each individual line.

So I'd suggest using a Bash array that you'd populate with this file (but this is obviously not the only possible solution):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file1="pet_list.txt"
while read -r line1 || [[ -n "$line1" ]]; do
  readarray -t lines2 < "$line1.breed.txt"  # needs `bash --version` ≥4.0
  for i in "${!lines2[@]}"; do
    echo "My pet is a $line1 and the breed is ${lines2[i]}"
  done
done < "$file1"
```

### Side notes:

- First, as suggested by @markp-fuso in the comments, I replaced the second occurrence of `file1` with another name (say, `line1`) because otherwise there is some ambiguity in the script with two semantically-different variables (w.r.t. their scope) but with the same identifier.
- Second, I replaced `$line1.breed.txt` with `"$line1.breed.txt"` (given it's mandatory to ["double-quote each $variable in Bash"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to avoid word splitting and glob expansion).
- Next, the mere `while read -r line1; do …; done < "$file1"` construct would require that the file ends with a newline.
  To lift this requirement, in line with [the first article in wooledge.org's Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21), I added some `|| [[ -n "$line1" ]]` construct (which is important to include in the general case).
- Finally, the solution above relies on `Bash arrays`; for more details on this feature, you may want to take a look at the very nice [Bash FAQ/005 article from wooledge.org](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).
  Otherwise, see [@DavidC.Rankin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69078588/9164010) which does not rely on `Bash arrays` but introduces two nested `while read`-based loops.

Comment: Any reason simply using `"$file1.breed.txt"` wouldn't work instead of reading the file into an array and requiring a nested loop?

Comment: As I said, this was not the only possible algorithm ;) but given the OP wants to loop over each line of `"$file1.breed.txt"` (which may contains several lines) and append the same prefix for each of these lines, I'm unsure there is a simpler algorithm(?)

Comment: Except if you want to do something like `cat "$file1.breed.txt" | sed -e 's/^/…prefix…/'`, but maybe that'd be less idiomatic than an array(?)

Comment: Yes that's file. I'll add the alternative.

Comment: while it works, and I'm guessing you're just tweaking OPs code, I'd steer away from the dual use of the `$file1` variable ... could be confusing for a newbie

Comment: Indeed, thanks @markp-fuso for the remark: even if the script so obtained in my answer was `shellcheck`-compliant, it's true that the two different (semantically different) occurrences of `$file1` are confusing; will change this.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to concatenate strings (or variables and a string) in bash, you can simply place the parts together to form a new string. For example, when you read from `pet_list.txt` into the variable `file1`, you can simply do:

```
"$file1.breed.txt"
```

to append `".breed.txt"` to the end of the contents in variable `$file1`. The only **caveat** is when the 1st character of the string to be appended could also be part of the variable name. (for instance in you were appending `"_breed.txt"`) In that case you must **guard** your variable name with braces, e.g.

```
"${file1}_breed.txt"
```

Guarding with braces prevents the variable from being interpreted as `"$file1_breed"` (the `'.'` can't be part of a variable name so the guards are not needed in your case)

Using simple concatenation, you could do something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## validate one argument given for filename
[ -z "$1" ] && {
    printf "error: filename required.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

## validate file is readable and non-empty
[ -s "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: file '%s' is empty or unreadable.\n" "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

## loop over entries in file
while read -r file1 || [ -n "$file1" ]; do
    ## test .breed.txt file exists and is non-empty
    breedfile="$file1.breed.txt"
    [ -s "$breedfile" ] || {
        printf "error: breed file '%s' empty or not found.\n" "$breedfile" >&2
        exit 1
    }
    ## loop reading breeds from breedfile into variable file2, output result
    while read -r file2 || [ -n "$file2" ]; do
        printf "My pet is a %s and the breed is %s\n" "$file1" "$file2"
    done < "$breedfile"
done < "$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the script in `script.sh` and your files in the names given, you would have:

```
 bash script.sh pet_list.txt
My pet is a dog and the breed is chowchow
My pet is a dog and the breed is pitbull
My pet is a dog and the breed is bulldog
My pet is a cat and the breed is sphynx
My pet is a cat and the breed is Bengal
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.